# How to create new branch and push local to code to github from macos commandline

Tags: xcode, git, github, version-control

I am trying to creating new branch in github, but I would like t create empty branch first and then I would to push my local xcode project to that new branch.

But, I have master branch in github already. While I am trying to create new branch in github website, its taking source branch from master branch, But, I want to create new branch without any source branch.

Note: Using terminal I am less aware, I am using Sourcetree.

So, If I would create empty branch without existing master branch code, I can push new/updated code to that newly created branch, that is what I am trying to do. So, I would like to push/commit fresh code to new empty branch.
Some of my co-worker long back created master branch, but, I would like to create new branch without disturbing old code.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you want to create a branch attach to nothing? That's the whole point of branches, they share at some point a common ancestor, no? You could go to the first commit of master and create a branch from there in SourceTree (or Terminal).

Comment: If I would create empty branch without existing master branch code, I can push new/updated code to that branch, that is what I am trying to do. S, I would like to push fresh code

Comment: @Larme thanks for the quick response, I have updated my lines, pls check once again.